# Centering a very long table of 8 pages in IEEE TRANS latex template which is double column format

Tags: tables, tabularx

This is the example of a very long table that I have already used in latex template of single-column format. But when I am using the same in double-column format, it's not showing properly and giving errors.  Even in double-column format, I want to make it spread entire the full width of the page. The output is also attached as an image. Please help me to resolve this issue.[image]

```
    \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   % \usepackage{subfigure}
   \usepackage{subfig}
     \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{tablefootnote}
       \usepackage{hyperref}
     \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
      \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
         \usepackage[demo,
         export]{adjustbox}
       \usepackage{stfloats}
      \usepackage{makecell,
        ltablex}    % new
       \keepXColumns
     % \raggedbottom
     % \usepackage{parskip} 
      \setcellgapes{3pt}
     \usepackage{enumitem}

      \usepackage{siunitx}
      %%
      %% \BibTeX command to typeset BibTeX logo in the docs

        \AtBeginDocument{%
            \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
           \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern- 0.8em\TeX}}}


              \begin{document}

        \begin{abstract}
     Substantial progress has been made recently on developing provably 
  accurate and efficient algorithms for low-rank
    matrix factorization via nonconvex optimization. While conventional 
    wisdom often takes a dim view of nonconvex optimization
    algorithms due to their susceptibility to spurious local minima,
      simple iterative methods such as gradient descent have been remarkably 
    successful in practice. The theoretical footings, however, had been 
       largely lacking until recently. In this tutorial-style
   overview, we highlight the important role of statistical models
   in enabling efficient nonconvex optimization with performance
     guarantees. We review two contrasting approaches: (1) two-stage
     algorithms, which consist of a tailored initialization step followed
     by successive refinement; and (2) global landscape analysis and
     initialization-free algorithms. Several canonical matrix factorization 
    problems are discussed, including but not limited to matrix
   sensing, phase retrieval, matrix completion, blind deconvolution,
  and robust principal component analysis. Special care is taken to
    illustrate the key technical insights underlying their analyses. This
    article serves as a testament that the integrated consideration of
     optimization and statistics leads to fruitful research findings..
      \end{abstract}


      \begingroup
        \setlist[itemize]{nosep,           % <-- itemize setup
              leftmargin = *,
              before     = \vspace{-.6\baselineskip},
              after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
              }
     % \makegapedcells                             % for additional vertical 
  space around cells' contents
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,height=12mm} % all images will have width 
   of cell's width
     \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
                          % for better fit text into cells
      \scriptsize
     \onecolumn
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{%
                    |*{1}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.07\linewidth}|}
                        *{1}{> 
           {\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.05\linewidth}|}
                                *{1}{> 
       {\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.1\linewidth}|}
                    %   *{1}{> 
       {\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.09\linewidth}|}
                    *{1}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.12\linewidth}|}
                        *{1}{> 
       {\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.11\linewidth}|}
                     *{1}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}
                        }
      % \centering              
        \caption{\textbf{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}}
          %   \label{tab:tablossless}                                             
\\
      \hline
       \thead{\textbf{ABCD}} 
       & \thead{\textbf{ABCD}}     
     & \thead{\textbf{ABCD}} 

     % &  \thead{\specialcell{\textbf{Loss}} \\\ 
   \specialcell{\textbf{Function}}}
        & \thead{\specialcell{\textbf{A} \\\ \specialcell{\textbf{B}}} }   
    & \thead{\specialcell{\textbf{C} \\\ \& \specialcell{\textbf{D}}} }  
        & \thead{\textbf{E}}     \\
           \hline
        \endfirsthead

         \endhead
      \multicolumn{6}{r}{\textit{continued on the next page}}
      \endfoot
          \endlastfoot

       \hline

       \textbf{A}  2016 &  a  & a        & a \& a
          & \begin{itemize}
      \item a
           \item a
       \end{itemize} 
       &  \begin{itemize}
     \item a
        \item a
           \item a
       \end{itemize} \\
        \hline

        \textbf{B}  a &a & a     &    a  & \begin{itemize}
           \item a
         \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}

         \item a
         \item a
          \item a
        \end{itemize}\\
          \hline

        \textbf{C}  &a  & a &        a,   a
                        & \begin{itemize}
           \item a
              \item as
        \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
     \item a
      \item a
        \end{itemize} \\
     \hline

      \textbf{D}  2019 & a  & a, a  & a   & a & \begin{itemize}
         \item a
        \item a
       \end{itemize}\\
        \hline

        \textbf{E}      &  a, a & \begin{itemize}
        \item a
         \item a
         \end{itemize} 
     &  \begin{itemize}
    \item a
  \item a
 \item a
     \end{itemize} 
       & \begin{itemize}
          \item a
         \item a
         \item a
      \end{itemize} \\
          \hline

        \textbf{A}  2016 &  a  & a        & a \& a
           & \begin{itemize}
              \item a
         \item a
         \end{itemize} 
         &  \begin{itemize}
          \item a
           \item a
               \item a
       \end{itemize} \\
         \hline

          \textbf{B}  a &a & a     &    a  & \begin{itemize}
             \item a
         \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}

           \item a
              \item a
         \item a
      \end{itemize}\\
         \hline

      \textbf{C}  2018 & a  &  a &        a, a \& a
      & \begin{itemize}
          \item a
        \item as
        \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
           \item a
          \item a
     \end{itemize} \\
    \hline

     \textbf{D}  2019 & a  & a, a  & a   & a & \begin{itemize}
       \item a
        \item a
     \end{itemize}\\
       \hline

         \textbf{E}      &  a, a & \begin{itemize}
          \item a
          \item a
      \end{itemize} 
         & \begin{itemize}
          \item a
        \item a
          \item a
       \end{itemize} 
    & \begin{itemize}
            \item a
         \item a
            \item a
       \end{itemize} \\
       \hline
    \textbf{A}  2016 &  a  & a        & a \& a
   & \begin{itemize}
           \item a
         \item a
         \end{itemize} 
       &  \begin{itemize}
       \item a
           \item a
      \item a
      \end{itemize} \\
           \hline

         \textbf{B}  a &a & a     &    a  & \begin{itemize}
                   \item a
       \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}

         \item a
        \item a
         \item a
        \end{itemize}\\
        \hline

      \textbf{C}  &a  & a &        a,   a
        & \begin{itemize}
      \item a
           \item as
         \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
  \item a
        \item a
       \end{itemize} \\
           \hline

     \textbf{D}  2019 & a  & a, a  & a   & a & \begin{itemize}
    \item a
          \item a
        \end{itemize}\\
          \hline

       \textbf{E}      &  a, a & \begin{itemize}
            \item a
            \item a
  \end{itemize} 
  & \begin{itemize}
         \item a
       \item a
           \item a
         \end{itemize} 
       & \begin{itemize}
        \item a
         \item a
             \item a
    \end{itemize} \\
 \hline

      \textbf{A}  2016 &  a  & a        & a \& a
        & \begin{itemize}
      \item a
      \item a
     \end{itemize} 
        &  \begin{itemize}
        \item a
\item a
        \item a
     \end{itemize} \\
          \hline

    \textbf{B}  a &a & a     &    a  & \begin{itemize}
    \item a
      \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}

       \item a
      \item a
\item a
      \end{itemize}\\
       \hline

   \textbf{C}  2018 & a  &  a &        a, a \& a
    & \begin{itemize}
\item a
         \item as
   \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
        \item a
           \item a
    \end{itemize} \\
      \hline

       \textbf{D}  2019 & a  & a, a  & a   & a & \begin{itemize}
        \item a
       \item a
            \end{itemize}\\
            \hline

           \textbf{E}      &  a, a & \begin{itemize}
      \item a
     \item a
         \end{itemize} 
        & \begin{itemize}
                 \item a
       \item a
   \item a
    \end{itemize} 
       & \begin{itemize}
       \item a
       \item a
     \end{itemize} \\
   \hline
       \textbf{A}  2016 &  a  & a        & a \& a
        & \begin{itemize}
      \item a
          \item a
             \end{itemize} 
       &  \begin{itemize}
           \item a
          \item a
     \item a
             \end{itemize} \\
    \hline

      \textbf{B}  a &a & a     &    a  & \begin{itemize}
       \item a
     \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}

      \item a
         \item a
      \item a
            \end{itemize}\\
         \hline

   \textbf{C}  &a  & a &        a,   a
     & \begin{itemize}
        \item a
      \item as
       \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
        \item a
         \item a
   \end{itemize} \\
          \hline

             \textbf{D}  2019 & a  & a, a  & a   & a & \begin{itemize}
        \item a
       \item a
          \end{itemize}\\
    \hline

           \textbf{E}      &  a, a & \begin{itemize}
                 \item a
      \item a
   \end{itemize} 
    & \begin{itemize}
  \item a
   \item a
      \item a
     \end{itemize} 
    & \begin{itemize}
  \item a
 \item a
 \item a
    \end{itemize} \\
    \hline

     \textbf{A}  2016 &  a  & a        & a \& a
      & \begin{itemize}
       \item a
     \item a
       \end{itemize} 
             &  \begin{itemize}
       \item a
                         \item a
        \item a
         \end{itemize} \\
         \hline

           \textbf{B}  a &a & a     &    a  & \begin{itemize}
       \item a
        \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}

      \item a
         \item a
      \item a
       \end{itemize}\\
        \hline

       \textbf{C}  2018 & a  &  a &        a, a \& a
        & \begin{itemize}
            \item a
         \item as
      \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
      \item a
        \item a
       \end{itemize} \\
            \hline

        \textbf{D}  2019 & a  & a, a  & a   & a & \begin{itemize}
        \item a
                \item a
      \end{itemize}\\
         \hline

         \textbf{E}      &  a, a & \begin{itemize}
           \item a
        \item a
     \end{itemize} 
            & \begin{itemize}
        \item a
      \item a
         \item a
       \end{itemize} 
          & \begin{itemize}
      \item a
        \item a
          \item a
        \end{itemize} \\
           \hline




            \hline
            \end{tabularx}
           \label{tablossless}
           \endgroup


         [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: I tried this, it worked but then a long page is left blank, whenever I am using this \onecolumn. Also after finishing the table I again changed the format to \twocolumn but still,  two to three pages are blank

Comment: Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example, or with the same problem given above....because I am using the same?, as I tried but its not working

Comment: I have updated full fetails with the output, please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108007/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-dipti-mishra).

Comment: In mine, there is no such error. But output which is shown is not desired. Earlier I have used, but it gave problem when table switch from one page to other pages, as my table is 8 pages long, that's why I have used tabular and it's quite working well in single column template, but not working in double-column format

Comment: @please use the chat at the link given here..

Comment: Table is fine, but I want table to start just below the text which is on first page, which is blank after abstract

Comment: `\onecolumn` automatically inserts a pagebreaks, hence the table can not start at teh same page as the abstract.

Comment: so then what should I do to solve this

Comment: please use the discussion link above.